# validating uploaded file size and type in php

Tags: php, validation, pdf, file-upload

I want to allow only PDF and MS word files and size must be less than 2MB,
here is my code:

```
 $mimes = array(
              'application/pdf',
              'application/x-pdf',
              'application/acrobat',
              'application/msword',
              'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
             ); 

if(!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $mimes)) {
    $msg1='<div class="alert alert-error">Invalid file format, Please choose only PDF or MS word files</div>';
} elseif($_FILES['file']['size']>2097152){
    $msg2='<div class="alert alert-error">The file is too large,(must be < 2MB)</div>';
}
```

**My problem is:**
When I choose pdf file with size >2MB **$msg1** is displayed instead of **$msg2**

I want to show **$msg1** when file is not PDF or MS Word file , 
and **$msg2** when file is >2MB

any help plz????

Comment: try var_dum($_FILES) and see structure of array.Probably $_FILES['file']['type'] is null

Comment: i tried it is not empty, it print the array,

Answer (score 2):

If u have

```
 <form ...>
    <input id='upload' name='upload'>
 </form>
```

You must test $_FILES['upload']['size'] > 2097152

Comment: that is what i did,but stil the problem is not solved

Comment: you display $msg1 and $msg2?

Comment: yeah i display when this error occur ,else i upload the file...and when i choose smaller PDF or ms word file  it works fine, if i choose other format like image of csv...it validate fine. but for lager PDF file it sayes the file format is invalid

Answer (score 0):

This is because.. Your first condition become wrong when you uploads the pdf file. when you trying to upload a file with greater than 2M size, 
$_FILES['file']['type'] 
returns a null value. The reason lies in your php.ini file. go and find the line 'upload_max_filesize'. it will be probably sett to 2M.so due to this the type returns an empty string.

Comment: so am i suposed to change the size in php.ini to what size so that it wont return null?